# How should I organize bintray packages for maven projects in bintray/jcenter?

Tags: artifactory, bintray, jcenter

I've tried again yesterday and failed once more to understand it. I have several projects. Each project produces several artifacts with group id `org.jgrapes`. With Sonatype, things are simple. I've succeeded to convince them that I own the domain `jgrapes.org`. Now I can simply publish the artifacts. ("Simply" with the exception that I experience upload problems lately and therefore consider bintray for publishing.) But I don't get the mapping of maven terms to bintray terms.

1. Sonatype Nexus --> a bintray maven repository (got that one)
2. One project --> one bintray package? (I'd like that because it reflects my project structure. But I doubt that this is right. I've got the impression that I cannot have several bintray packages containing artifacts with the same group id (if I want them to be linked to jcenter), or can I?)
3. All artifacts from all projects --> one bintray package? (This seems most likely. It would mean that one bintray package links to one subtree in the bintray maven repository that represents all artifacts with the same group id. Is this correct?)
4. One artifact (unique group-id/artifact-id) --> one bintray package? (This seems ridiculous, because I'd have to request inclusion in bintray for each new artifact, but as mentioned, I currently fail to really understand.)
5. (4) + "bintray merge package" that links to jcenter? (I found out about merge packages yesterday and it didn't really make things easier...)

To summarize: I want a configuration that allows me to push new artifacts (all with grouid `org.jgrapes`) to bintray in such a way that they appear in jcenter automatically (that's what currently happens when I publish using Sonatype/Nexus).